# Drupal 7 form managed file default value not working

Tags: forms, file, drupal-7, managed

I'm using druapl 7 form to allow users to upload images for a slideshow.  The managed file is working great to upload and save the files and I can see the entries in the database.  All is good when nothing is there.  But when the form is reloaded, I cannot get the the default value working for the uploaded image.

```
$form['slideshow_0_slide_0_fieldset']['slideshow_0_slide_0_image'] = array(
    '#name' => "files[slideshow_0_slide_0_image]",
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#size' => '25',
    '#title' => t('Image 0'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#default_value' => variable_get( $managed_file_fid, '' )
);
```

I've also tried this without success:

```
'#default_value' => file_load( $managed_file_fid, '' )
```

What am I missing here to get the default value working?

Comment: Seems I was over-thinking this one.  Just needed to use $managed_file_fid var alone.

'#default_value' => $managed_file_fid,